# PyQt QTabBar is not creating new tabs

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtabbar

I am trying to add new tabs into a QTabBar and it has been unsuccessful.

What I am trying to achieve is that when you click onto the 'add' icon, there will be 3 menu items. Depending on which item is selected, it will create a new tab besides the 'add' icon.

For example, if I selected the option - `food`, the gui will appear something as follows:

`| + | food |`

In my `set_new_tab()`, while it appears to have printed out the option I have selected, the `addTab` does not seems to be doing anything.

Wondering if I have missed out something, or if a `QTabBar` should be used in conjunction with `QTabWidget`?

This is my code:

```
class MyWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__()

        self.tab_bar = QtGui.QTabBar()
        self.add_button = QtGui.QToolButton(self)
        self.add_button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('add.png'))
        self.add_button.setMenu(self.set_menu())
        self.add_button.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)

        self.tab_bar.setTabButton(
            0,
            QtGui.QTabBar.ButtonPosition.RightSide,
            self.add_button
        )

    def set_menu(self):
        menu_options = ['food', 'drinks', 'snacks']
        qmenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.add_button)

        for opt in menu_options:
            qmenu.addAction(opt, partial(self.set_new_tab, opt))
        qmenu.addAction
        return qmenu

    def set_new_tab(self, opt):
        print ">>> opt clicked on : ", opt
        self.tab_bar.addTab(opt) # This does not seems to creating new tabs..
```

Appreciate for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not to create in the tabs but in that the size of the tab is small and is behind the button, so the solution is to use the layouts to place the widgets correctly.

```
from functools import partial
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class MyWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWin, self).__init__()
        central_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        vlay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        hlay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        vlay.addLayout(hlay)
        vlay.addStretch()

        self.add_button = QtGui.QToolButton()
        self.tab_bar = QtGui.QTabBar(self)
        self.add_button.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('add.png'))
        self.add_button.setMenu(self.set_menu())
        self.add_button.setPopupMode(QtGui.QToolButton.InstantPopup)

        self.tab_bar.setTabButton(
            0,
            QtGui.QTabBar.ButtonPosition.RightSide,
            self.add_button
        )
        hlay.addWidget(self.add_button)
        hlay.addWidget(self.tab_bar)

    def set_menu(self):
        menu_options = ['food', 'drinks', 'snacks']
        qmenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.add_button)
        for opt in menu_options:
            qmenu.addAction(opt, partial(self.set_new_tab, opt))
        qmenu.addAction
        return qmenu

    def set_new_tab(self, opt):
        print(">>> opt clicked on : ", opt)
        self.tab_bar.addTab(opt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Got it, wasn't aware that it was behind the button... Thank you. Also, can I kindly ask if I can query all the tabs made by the `addTab`? This is because I would not want to add in duplicated items...

Comment: @TehKi use [QString QTabBar::tabText(int index) const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#tabText) with [int count() const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabbar.html#count-prop)

Comment: Thank you, I did saw the `count()` but not `tabText` and it works now. :)